# Send custom ajax data object from pseudo form (div) within form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a sign-up form, I am wanting to add a file upload mid way through the process. Meaning I have to have the upload process behave differently to the sign-up form, however, I am having issues posting custom data fields (namely the FILES input) through to the ajax handler.

```
<div class="doc_upload_area">
  <input type="hidden" name="propertyId" value="<? echo $tempPropertyId; ?>" />
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="file" class="form-control file_upload" name="the_file" aria-label="Upload">
    <select required class="form-select document_id" name="document_type" >
      <option value="">Tell us what your uploading</option>
      <option value="document">Document</option>
      <option value="brochure">Brochure</option>      
    </select>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary doc_upload" type="submit">Upload</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the main part of the jQuery in question, as you can see I have attempted to serialise the div, I only have two fields I need to pass into the data to send across to the handler...

```
$(".doc_upload").on('click',(function(e) {
   var x = $(".doc_upload_area").serializeArray();
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      url: "../document_upload.php",
      type: "POST",
      data:  x
```

Comment: You need to use a FormData object when sending binary data in the AJAX request. The duplicate covers how to create the request in JS to include the file, and how to receive the data in PHP.

Comment: Wonderful! Works like a dream.